# Вывод количества пользователей

Tags: php, mysql

Как осуществить вывод окончания, если 1 юзер, то пишет " 1 пользователь, " если 2, 3, 4, то "пользователЯ", если 6, то "пользователЕЙ".

Внизу код, который надо под это подредактировать.

```
<?php

$user_count = user_count();
$suffix = ($user_count !=1) ? 'ей' : 'ь';

?>
у нас <?php echo $user_count; ?> пользовател<?php echo $suffix; ?> зарегистрировано
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$users = array('Пользователей','Пользователь','Пользователя'); // 0,1,2

if( $user_count%100 >= 5 && $user_count%100 < 21) $form = 0;
else if( $user_count % 10 == 1) $form = 1;
else if( in_array( $user_count % 10, array(2,3,4), TRUE)) $form = 2;
else $form = 0;

printf( '<p>У нас %d %s</p>', $user_count, $users[$form]);
```

Comment: проверьте свой алгоритм на числах 111..114

Comment: о спасибо заработало)

Comment: @xEdelweiss, спасибо, сам поленился проверить. Починил.

Answer (score 0):

Отредактировать под *это* попробуйте сами, а [вот](http://unicode.org/repos/cldr-tmp/trunk/diff/supplemental/language_plural_rules.html) вам подсказка, как это делается.

Пользовател**ь**: `(n mod 10 = 1) AND (n mod 100 != 11)`
Пользовател**я**: `(n mod 10 = 2..4) AND (n mod 100 != 12..14)`
Пользовател**ей**: `(n mod 10 = 0) OR (n mod 10 = 5..9) OR (n mod 100 = 11..14)`
Пользовател**я**: `остальное`

Answer (score -1):

можно использовать

```
                     `switch{

                         case variant_1:
                         echo"++++++";
                         break;

                         case variant_2:
                         echo"+-+-+";
                         break;
                     }`
```